# Showing Json Load Progress

Tags: c#, json, winforms, treeview, backgroundworker

I can load Json onto treeview, I can also show progress but not always. Let's say I have a dictionary inside an object inside json. I cannot get progress. These codes should explain:

```
//ShowTreeview() calls backgroundWorker's DoWork

DoWork(...) {
     AddObjectNodes(args...);
}
AddObjectNodes(args...) {
    int Index = 0;
    foreach (... in @object) {
    AddTokenNodes(...);
    int Count = @object.Count; //Only counts top tokens 
    int Ratio = 100 / Count;
    jsonProgress.Maximum = Ratio * Count;
    worker.ReportProgress( Ratio * Index++);
}
}

//Setting progressbar value on ProgressChanges
```

So I want to show progress of sub-nodes as well.
And the other thing is; Why UI stops even with background worker.
Regards.

Comment: Can you please show your BG worker code?

Comment: @pix DoWork is the worker code.